# Excel calculations

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet calculator that adds several numbers to one another to make a total

Hence A1+A2+A3 = A4  assume 2+3+4 answer = 9 = A4 (and linked to D6 in Sheet 2)

I want to store this answer 9 on a separate sheet, then resue the same calculator above for my second calculation and store the new answer alongside the 9 on the second sheet.

Each time i run my present calculator, the sumed number 9 on sheet 2 is continouely updated and I lose the orginal answer on the 2nd pass.

Any help would be apprecvated as I need a list of 12 calucluations and answers spreed across my sheet 2

Comment: Does it work for you if you copy the formula (i.e. A4) for 12 times, each of them referred by the corresponding cell in Sheet2?  Otherwise it seems you will need a bit of VBA programming.

Comment: You want to run the calculation, then replace the numbers in a1, a2 and a3 with new numbers and have that be stored next to D6? Not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to duplicate or fill down/right the formulas for every input you want or record a macro that does the following

1. moves all previous answers (pasted in step 3) down/across one cell
2. copies the current answer
3. then "paste value" into the first position of the list of answers

Spreadsheet programs like Excel are not designed to store previous rounds/steps of calculations.  Also keep in mind there is a "goal seek" menu option for automatically seeking the correct input to make the calculated result the desired value.